# If $A$ and $B$ are real, symmetric, positive definite matrices, then prove that $A(A+B)^{-1}B$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

> If $A$ and $B$ are real, symmetric, positive definite matrices, then prove that $A(A+B)^{-1}B$ is positive definite.

If $A$ and $B$ are positive definite, then $A+B$ is positive definite, and inverse of a positive definite matrix is positive definite. So $(A+B)^{-1}$ is positive definite. I don't know how to proceed after that.

Please anyone help me solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by positive-definite? Nonnegative quadratic form? Usually it refers just to symmetric matrices, but your matrix here is not symmetric...

Comment: @J.G $A$ is positive definite means $x^TAx>0$ for any non-zero $x$.

Comment: @J.G. This convention is also common.  $A$ by this notion is positive definite if and only if $A + A^T$ is (symmetric and) positive definite.

Comment: @J.G. As it turns out, this matrix is necessarily symmetric

Comment: @Omnomnomnom woah, I totally didn’t expect that! I’ll admit I should’ve checked more carefully before making that statement, but it’s actually a bit surprising it’s symmetric...thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's true because $A(A+B)^{-1}B=\left[B^{-1}(A+B)A^{-1}\right]^{-1}=(B^{-1}+A^{-1})^{-1}$ and the sum or inverses of any symmetric positive definite matrices are symmetric positive definite.

Comment: That's really nifty

Answer (score 3):

Note that $M = A(A + B)^{-1}B$ is positive definite if and only if $M + M^T$ is symmetric and positive definite. Also, $(A + B)^{-1}$ is symmetric since it is the inverse of a symmetric matrix.  Now,

Note that
$$
A(A + B)^{-1}B = \\
(A+B-B)(A+B)^{-1}B = \\
(A+B)(A+B)^{-1}B - B(A+B)^{-1}B = \\
B - B(A + B)^{-1}B = \\
B[B^{-1} - (A + B)^{-1}]B
$$
Now, it suffices to show that $B^{-1} - (A + B)^{-1}$ is positive semidefinite.  This proof is quick if you're familiar with the [Loewner ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order), but one direct proof would be as follows.  Note that
$$
A \quad \text{is positive semidefinite} \iff\\
(A + B) - B \quad \text{is positive semidefinite} \iff\\
B^{-1/2}(A + B)B^{-1/2} - I \quad \text{is positive semidefinite} \iff\\
B^{-1/2}(A + B)B^{-1/2} \quad \text{is symmetric with eigenvalues greater than $1$} \iff\\
[B^{-1/2}(A + B)B^{-1/2}]^{-1} \quad \text{is symmetric with eigenvalues less than $1$} \iff\\
B^{1/2}(A + B)^{-1}B^{1/2} \quad \text{is symmetric with eigenvalues less than $1$} \iff\\
I - B^{1/2}(A + B)^{-1}B^{1/2}\quad \text{is positive semidefinite} \iff\\
B^{-1} - (A + B)^{-1} \quad \text{is positive semidefinite}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Given $\rm A, B \succ \mathrm O_n$, we form the following block matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A + \mathrm B & \mathrm A\\ \mathrm A & \mathrm A\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_n & \mathrm I_n\\ & \mathrm I_n\end{bmatrix} \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm B & \\ & \mathrm A\end{bmatrix}}_{\succ \mathrm O_{2n}} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_n & \\ \mathrm I_n & \mathrm I_n\end{bmatrix} \succ \mathrm O_{2n}$$

and, using the Schur complement, we conclude that

$$\mathrm A - \mathrm A \left( \mathrm A + \mathrm B \right)^{-1} \mathrm A \succ \mathrm O_n$$

Note that

$$\mathrm I_n = \left( \mathrm A + \mathrm B \right)^{-1} \left( \mathrm A + \mathrm B \right) = \left( \mathrm A + \mathrm B \right)^{-1} \mathrm A + \left( \mathrm A + \mathrm B \right)^{-1} \mathrm B$$

and, hence,

$$\left( \mathrm A + \mathrm B \right)^{-1} \mathrm B = \mathrm I_n - \left( \mathrm A + \mathrm B \right)^{-1} \mathrm A$$

Left-multiplying both sides by $\rm A$,

$$\mathrm A \, \left( \mathrm A + \mathrm B \right)^{-1} \mathrm B = \mathrm A - \mathrm A \left( \mathrm A + \mathrm B \right)^{-1} \mathrm A \succ \mathrm O_n$$

Comment: Using the other Schur complement, $$\left( \mathrm A + \mathrm B \right) - \mathrm A \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm A  = \mathrm B \succ \mathrm O_n$$ as suggested in a comment that was posted but later deleted.